# Python-Failing to insert into sqlite table when using a function

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to run this script by calling the `insert()` function with the following variables: `insert("vocations", "vocation_name", vocation)`

```
def insert(tablename,columnname,list):
    print("This is the table we are inserting into : ", str(tablename))
    print("This is the column name we are inserting into : ", columnname)
    print("This is the list we are using to insert values :", list)


    for elem in list:
        conn = sqlite3.connect('autogendb.db')
        c = conn.cursor()
        #print(elem)
        tablename=tablename
        columnname=columnname
        elemval=str(elem)
        print("ElemVal : " + elemval)
        #c.execute("INSERT INTO tablename(columnname)  VALUES (?)", (elem)")


       #c.execute("INSERT INTO RecordONE (Number, Name) VALUES(?, ?)", (number, name))

        #sqlq="\"INSERT INTO " + tablename + "(" + columnname + ")" + " VALUES" + "(?)" + "\"" + "," + "['" + elem + "']"
        sqlq="\"INSERT INTO " + tablename + "(" + columnname + ")" + " VALUES" + "(?)" + "\""

        print(sqlq)
        #c.execute("INSERT INTO vocations(vocation_name) VALUES(?)", ['merchant'])
        c.execute(sqlq, (elemval))
        conn.commit()
```

when I run it I get the following :

```
This is the table we are inserting into :  vocations
This is the column name we are inserting into :  vocation_name
This is the list we are using to insert values : {'forester', 'knight', 'merchant'}
ElemVal : forester
"INSERT INTO vocations(vocation_name) VALUES(?)"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Dropbox\Dropbox\PythonCourse\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\Chivalry&Sorcery\ClassVersion\Characterbackground\autogeneratebackground.py", line 93, in <module>
    createdbtables()
  File "D:\Dropbox\Dropbox\PythonCourse\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\Chivalry&Sorcery\ClassVersion\Characterbackground\autogeneratebackground.py", line 60, in createdbtables
    insert("vocations", "vocation_name", vocation)
  File "D:\Dropbox\Dropbox\PythonCourse\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\Chivalry&Sorcery\ClassVersion\Characterbackground\autogeneratebackground.py", line 57, in insert
    c.execute(sqlq, (elemval))
sqlite3.OperationalError: near ""INSERT INTO vocations(vocation_name) VALUES(?)"": syntax error
```

Please help identifying what I have done wrong